# How can I replace one string variable in any row with a particular value?

Tags: stata

Within `rfcolumn`, I am trying to `replace` all values of `"bad"` with `"good"`.

I have used the command:

```
replace rfcolumn = "good" in 10
```

and this will replace `"good"` with `"bad"` in row 10.

Comment: I've edited out references to renaming as irrelevant here, but left in references to rows, because that is arguably poor use of terminology to be corrected by the OP. That's a fine. perhaps arbitrary, distinction.

Comment: Thanks, Nick. I am new to Stata and appreciate the guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Stata is not a spreadsheet application: the terminology of rows and columns is used only for matrices. Sure, it is possible to translate, but using non-Stata terminology in Stata is to be avoided as much as the reverse. For columns, always say variables; for rows, always say observations.

To `replace` all values equal to `"bad"` with `"good"`

```
replace rfcolumn = "good" if rfcolumn == "bad"
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it.